# IIS7 URL Rewrite for URL with &rsquo;

Tags: iis-7, rewrite

I'm trying to redirect the following URL in IIS7 using the URL Rewrite module:

```
Category/Cat-3/Objectives-of-Pre-Maintenance/WHAT&rsquo;S-THE-STORY-ON-LOW-CARB-DIETS-AND-EXERCISE-.aspx
```

but for the life of me I can not get it. I tried replacing the `&rsquo;` with an actual single quote, and that worked fine! But for the purpose of this redirect, I need the HTML code for the quote, and not the quote itself. Here is the rule from web config:

```
<rule name="Redirect" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^Category/Cat-3/Objectives-of-Pre-Maintenance/WHAT&amp;rsquo;S-THE-STORY-ON-LOW-CARB-DIETS-AND-EXERCISE-\.aspx" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/redirecturl/" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
```

Any ideas would be very helpful! Thanks

Comment: "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&)". The & char is reserved for querystring only. It needs to be url encoded for the character to pass.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this code? `&#39;`

Comment: The links I need redirected point to the URL with &rsquo; so I have to do it using that code, I assume